# More advanced PowerShell Encoding or encrypting functions

Tags: powershell

I am trying to obfuscate some PowerShell with more advanced encodings that use the PowerShell empire, but the problem continues. Has anyone written more advanced encoders (or cries) than below?

```
function Encode-Packet {
    Param([Int16]$type, $data, [Int16]$ResultID=0)
    <# 
        encode a packet for transport:
        +------+--------------------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
        | Type | total # of packets | packet # | task ID | Length | task data |
        +------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-----------+
        |  2   |         2          |    2     |    2    |   4    | <Length>  |
        +------+--------------------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+
    #>

    # in case we get a result array, make sure we join everything up
    if ($data -is [System.Array]) {
        $data = $data -join "`n"
    }

    # convert data to base64 so we can support all encodings and handle on server side
    $data = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($data))

    $packet = New-Object Byte[] (12 + $data.Length)

    # packet type
    ([BitConverter]::GetBytes($type)).CopyTo($packet, 0)
    # total number of packets
    ([BitConverter]::GetBytes([Int16]1)).CopyTo($packet, 2)
    # packet number
    ([BitConverter]::GetBytes([Int16]1)).CopyTo($packet, 4)
    # task/result ID
    ([BitConverter]::GetBytes($ResultID)).CopyTo($packet, 6)
    # length
    ([BitConverter]::GetBytes($data.Length)).CopyTo($packet, 8)
    ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($data)).CopyTo($packet, 12)

    $packet
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using protocols that already exist for this kind of thing?  Rolling your own encryption/encoding is a futile endeavor.

Comment: Yeah, never roll your own security.  Someone else whose job is to do *just that* has already done it and it's already been vetted by third party security researchers and certifications like FIPS 140-2 or some similar standards body.  This is why many services are built on top of HTTPS web servers: almost everything has already been done for you.

Comment: You're looking for the [`System.Security.Cryptography` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx).

Comment: The solution is never about encryption...it's about key management.